# Pointer initialization of a struct array

Tags: c++, struct

my application crashes when it comes to it.

So I have a struct like this for example(but in reality it has many more things)

```
struct Record
{
    float m_fSimulationTime;
    unsigned char m_szflags;
};
```

In my class I have it declared like this:

```
Record *m_record[64];
```

And then I initalize it: (and here the crash occoures (acces violation on read))

```
void ClassXYZ::initRecord()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 32; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            m_record[i][j].m_fSimulationTime = 0.0f; // here happens the crash
}
```

I hope you can help me out what I'm missing here x.x

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `m_record` is an array of pointers. You need to initialize the pointers first before you access them.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 32; i++)
{
    m_record[i] = new Record[9];  // Make the pointer actually point somewhere
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        m_record[i][j].m_fSimulationTime = 0.0f;

}
```

If the size `9` is fixed at the time of compilation, a better solution would be to use an array of arrays:

```
Record m_record[64][9];
```

In this case I would rather recommend using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead though.

If the size of either array is not know at compile-time, but input at run-time then use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Thanks I get it now, I will be better using vector :)